# SonataAdminBundle templates - list and show fields template content duplication

Tags: symfony, templates, twig, sonata-admin

My list and show fields contain the same content, but due the extending of `base_list_field` and `base_show_field` templates I have to create two separate templates.

list/location.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    {{ object.getCity }}, {{ object.getCountry.getName }}
{% endblock %}
```

show/location.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    {{ object.getCity }}, {{ object.getCountry.getName }}
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see huge part of code is duplicated. Is there a way to check the page I am currently in in twig and then extend certain base template? In this case I would be able to use one file instead of two for same content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `twig` it's possible to extend/include a dynamic template :

```
{# do test here on which page you are or pass through controller #}
{% if true %}
    {% set template = 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig' %}
{% else %}
   {% set template = 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %
{% endif %}
{% extends template %}

{% block field %}
    {{ object.getCity }}, {{ object.getCountry.getName }}
{% endblock %}
```

---

*(edit)* if you don't want the hardcoded if I would pass  the template variable through the controller and change the `twig template` to something like

```
{% extends template|default('SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig') %}
```

Comment: Not an accurate answer for the question, but if no one will answer more detailed I will mark it as correct. Got the _route and hardcoded IF condition as you said. Idk, but route name `admin_index_offer_show` for me looks sketchy to depend on in IF condition.